# Python rose chart

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

i was trying to build a windrose chart. i found this link to the code:
(http://youarealegend.blogspot.no/2008/09/windrose.html)

i get the following error, which points to numpy:
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2768: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in rint
  return round(decimals, out)

has anyone encountered this before?

here is the code:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from numpy.random import random
from numpy import arange

#Create wind speed and direction variables
ws = random(500)*6
wd = random(500)*360

#A quick way to create new windrose axes...
def new_axes():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w')
    rect = [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]
    ax = WindroseAxes(fig, rect, axisbg='w')
    fig.add_axes(ax)
    return ax

#...and adjust the legend box
def set_legend(ax):
    l = ax.legend(borderaxespad=-0.10)
    plt.setp(l.get_texts(), fontsize=8)

#A stacked histogram with normed (displayed in percent) results :

ax = new_axes()
ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
set_legend(ax)
```

Comment: That's a warning message rather than an error. Did the rest of the code work as expected? If not, what was the problem?

Comment: thanks for little kink - i had another look at the code and it is missing at the end: plt.show()